# How google-services.json file can be put to custom location within android project

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I am integrating firebase crashlytics from fabric to my android project and my project has many partners and I am building output for these all partner from android source set.

In firebase console, I have set up a debug and release 2 projects for each partner. so now google services plugin searches for google-services.json file for each partner and I want to put thes (2 google-services.json files) to custom location.

Can I provide custom location path to google services plugin for these files ?

During build time I can copy these json files to respective source set and plugin will find them.

Answer (score 3):

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Note that if you have multiple package names, but only the one file, you an add more clients to the file.

```
{
  "project_info": {...},
  "client": ["client_info": {..."package_name": "com.blundell.tut"],
  "client": ["client_info": {..."package_name": "com.ataul.tut"],
  "client": [...]
}
```

i.e. so instead of a custom location, you can have them all in the same file (and also modify the file in the fly if you wanted).

Answer (score 1):

you have to change your project stricture and select project from list -> select app -> and paste your google-services.json

Comment: comment if you have any query

Comment: Thanks. This is the standard location of this json file but my question is about to put this json file to the custom location.

Comment: no you can not put your json file on another location because this is the only folder which firebase always sync

Comment: Yes..you are right we currently we can't put this file to custom location and same I got from firebase official team

Comment: Appreciate the answer if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

The possibly locations of the configuration file can't be changed, and the location are [very well documented](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).  The typical solution in this case is to create different build flavors for each of your partners, and use the specific folder used for the build flavor in order to organize your configuration files.

Comment: Creating a new build flavor is not a solution to my problem. Do you know If I move this json file during build time to standard location then at which android task should I do this ?

Comment: You could do that, but it will be easier to use build flavors.